# Is it possible to place a fielder other than standard fielding positions?

Tags: rules, cricket, terminology, strategy, formations

Is it permitted to place the fielders other than the standard fielding positions terms in international cricket match?

To be more specific,

can a fielder be placed in

- between the mid-on and long-on
- straight back to keeper on the circle
- straight back to the bowler on the circle
- any other place which is not yet been given a place term(like fine leg, point..)

**Refer the red circles in the below image**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, such placements are generally allowed. Neither the [MCC's Laws of Cricket](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-41-the-fielder/) nor any of the [ICC's Playing Conditions](http://www.icc-cricket.com/about/38/rules-and-regulations) rule any such placements out.

> There are a number of named basic fielding positions, some of which are employed very commonly and others that are used less often. However, fielding positions are not fixed, and fielders can be placed in positions that differ from the basic positions. Most of the positions are named roughly according to a system of polar coordinates - one word (leg, cover, mid-wicket) specifies the angle from the batsman, and is optionally preceded by an adjective describing the distance from the batsman (silly, short, deep or long). Words such as "backward", "forward", or "square" can further indicate the angle.

<sup>[*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fielding_positions_in_cricket#Fielding_position_names_and_locations)</sup>

[image]

But keep in mind the fielding restrictions:

> Fielders may be placed anywhere on the field, subject to the following rules. At the time the ball is bowled:
>
> - No fielder may be standing on or with any part of his body over the pitch (the central strip of the playing area between the wickets). If his body casts a shadow over the pitch the shadow must not move until after the batsman has played (or had the opportunity to play) at the ball.
> - There may be no more than two fielders, other than the wicket-keeper, standing in the quadrant of the field behind square leg. See Bodyline for details on one reason this rule exists.
> - In some one-day matches:
>
>   - During designated overs of an innings (see Powerplay (cricket)), there may be no more than two fielders standing outside an oval line marked on the field, being semicircles centred on the middle stump of each wicket of radius 30 yards, joined by straight lines parallel to the pitch. This is known as the fielding circle. In addition, during these overs there must be two fielders (other than the wicket-keeper) in designated "close catching" positions.
>   - For the remainder of the innings there may be no more than four fielders standing outside the fielding circle.
>
>   The restriction for one-day cricket is designed to prevent the fielding team from setting extremely defensive fields and concentrating solely on preventing the batting team from scoring runs.

<sup>[*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fielding_positions_in_cricket#Restrictions_on_field_placement)</sup>

Comment: I've cut this off at the pass and removed the incorrect statement in the wiki page about players behind the keeper. Answer updated accordingly. If someone wants to add it back into the wiki page they should provide a citation.

Comment: @Bogdanovist Good idea. Unfortunately, looks like your Wikipedia edit was reverted, possibly by someone imagining it to be vandalism.

Answer (score 0):

1) This position is called deep mid on and is a perfectly legitimate position usually used when the batsmen is chipping over mid on but not trying to carry all the way for six.

2) Another perfectly legitimate position, this is called short stop (as opposed to the man on the fence, long stop), and is often seen in village cricket when a low quality wicket keeper is standing up to the spinner.

3) This is actually an illegal position as it is obstructing the batsmens sight line behind the bowlers arm, and he is perfectly at liberty to ask the opposition captain to move him to one side. The straight man on the fence you have drawn is similarly in an illegal position.

4) Where you have drawn the circle would probably be described as 'cow corner but twenty yards in', and used when a guy is slogging but not strong enough to clear the field.

Basically fielders can be placed anywhere except on the wicket, straight behind the bowlers arm, and no more than 2 behind square on leg. Ive seen a field of 3 slips, gully, third man, midwicket, forward cow corner, cow corner and backward cow corner set to a batsmen - the batsmen first drilled the ball over the three cow fielders for six, second ball swing and miss, third ball hit it straight to one of the cow fielders. If the batsmen had limited strokes the fielding captain is perfectly at liberty to put all his fielders where he knows the batsmen will hit it.

Comment: Your last paragraph is not quite true.  A fielder's shadow must not be cast on the wicket.